# Lua sin/cos в rad/deg

Tags: lua

Здравствуйте. У меня возник вопрос. Я использую wxWidgets, и пытаюсь сделать переходы от rad к deg и обратно, но у меня появилась проблема со счислением. Именно [данный код](http://pastebin.com/tJ2Wb5bL) работает некорректно. Поясню суть проблемы:

- При установке raddeg значения 2, не получается установить его в значение 1.
- Когда raddeg установлен на 2 (на градусы), cos считается неправильно (например cos90 (при raddeg = 2) = - 6.1230317691119e-017, несмотря на то, что Lua Demo при коде `print(math.cos(math.deg(90)))` даёт вообще значение -0.29951539475554)

На этом ошибки вроде закончились. Прошу помочь.

Comment: > например cos90 (при raddeg = 2) = - 6.1230317691119e-017

этот ответ очень похож на правду.

Comment: Но на самом же деле cos 90 градусов (градусы - это когда raddeg = 2) равен 0

Comment: @TraniLurese 

минус шесть умножить на **десять в минус семнадцатой степени**

сильно от нуля отличается по вашему ? :) 

[округляйте до 10го знака, например](http://ideone.com/Rsghy0) (я lua совсем не знаю, наверное первая моя строчка в жизни)

Comment: Сделал округление до 4го знака, и немного изменил структуру проверки. Теперь в радианах sin 90 = 1, cos 90 = 0;
а в градусах sin 90 = -0.9541, cos 90 = -0.2995
Тут похоже что радианы стали градусами, а градусы непонятно чем, но точно не радианами.